# Is it possible base64 png converted into array buffer and write in a pdf format

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have a random data like pdf, png, jpg and excel and got its Base64 formated string representation and i want to write these files in pdf format.

actually  i am using this node module "base64-arraybuffer" for converting into arraybuffer and then i write into pdf format but i works for only base64 pdf string

is there anyway to convert these files into pdf format

```
const base64 = require("base64-arraybuffer")
var fs = require("fs")
var path = require("path")
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;
fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "./png_base64.txt"), "utf8", (fileError, data) =>
{
    const arrayData = base64.decode(data)

    function createPDFFile(orderId, arrData) {
        fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,`./${orderId}.png`), Buffer.from(arrData) , function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("The file was saved!");
            }
        }); 
    }

    createPDFFile("base64pdf", arrayData)
})
```

Error
Failed to load PDF document

Comment: png and pdf are not written in the same format at all.
you should first convert the data from png format to pdf, then you can write it.

Comment: try using imagemagic library.